# Regular expression to match ${.*}

Tags: regex, testing, match

I want to match a string that have this `${anything-here}`

For example in this case:

```
outside${parameter1}outside${parameter2}
```

The regular expression must match:
`${parameter1}` as the first match
`${parameter2}` as the second match

I tried this:

```
\$\{.*}
```

But it matches:

```
${parameter1}outside${parameter2}
```

Because I don't know how to finish the match after the character `}`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: can you have multiple parameters, or just two at most?

Comment: What language/flavor of regex?

Comment: it's for apply with java and the Pattern and Matcher class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it non-greedy:

```
\${.*?}
```

OR better to use negation:

```
\${[^}]*}
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/MvmUpTC2n8

In this demo you can see it is matching `${parameter1}` and `${parameter2}`

**PS:** As @Tim commented below its better to escape `{` since some regex engines can throw an error. So better to use:

```
\${[^\}]*}
```

If you want to capture these matching texts inside the curly braces then you can use capture groups like this:

```
\${([^\}]*)}
```

Comment: Some regex engines throw an error on the unescaped braces because they try to interpret them as a `{n,m}` quantifier and fail. It's safer to escape them. And the capturing group should be inside of the braces, or group 1 will contain the same as group 0. But otherwise +1, especially for the version with negation.

Comment: Thanks @TimPietzcker: Your comments are always right on the money for me. I will edit my answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it lazy. It will match as little as possible.

```
 \$\{.*?\}
```

Example from python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "outside${parameter1}outside${parameter2}"
>>> regex = r'\$\{.*?\}'
>>> re.findall(regex, s)
['${parameter1}', '${parameter2}']
```

Comment: how does this regex match `parameter2`?

Comment: He needs to reapply the regex. There is not way to handle arbitrary numbers of matches without matching the whole regex and still getting all the groups out. Using something like preg_match_all or re.findall() gets them all.

Comment: @Bill: I guess that depends on the language the OP is using. Meaning it should provide functions which will return all matches of the expression.

Comment: @melwil Yes, as FelixKing said, it depends on language. Using Perl you can extract all matches at one shot.

Comment: Yes, but ideally you should escape the `}` at the end too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to capture the parameter into a group, like so:

```
\$\{([^}]*)}
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/HgBn35iZ8dE5nKez)

Answer (score 0):

`.*` would match till the last possible pattern.In your case it eats everything till the last `}`.So,it is **greedy**

`.*?` would match as less as possible.In other word it is **lazy**

So,you have three ways to do it

```
[$][{].*?[}]

[$][{][^}][}]

[$][{]\w+[}]
```